# Unable to set session under switch/case condition

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am unable to set session for $_SESSION['next'] under switch/case condition, while $_SESSION['user_id'] works perfectly before the condition. The script run into each condition of switch/case condition and redirect without setting $_SESSION['next']. Is there any specific reason why it fails to work? How to solve this?

```
require_once ('../src/facebook.php');
require_once ('../src/fbconfig.php');

//Facebook Authentication part
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user_id <> '0' && $user_id <> '') {
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

switch((isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '')){
    case 'abc';{
        $_SESSION['next'] = 'AAA';
        echo "<script>top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/'</script>";
        exit;}  
    case 'def';{
        $_SESSION['next'] = 'BBB'; 
        echo "<script>top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/'</script>";
        exit;}  
    case 'ghi';{
        $_SESSION['next'] = 'CCC'; 
        echo "<script>top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/'</script>";
        exit;}
    default;{
        echo "<script>top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/'</script>";
        exit;}                                                                                                                                                                              
}   

} else {
echo "<script>top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/'</script>";   
exit;
}
```

Comment: It's `break` in a `switch` - not `exit`. `exit` causes the script to end.

Comment: @Mihai there were many more things wrong with OP's code - they're in my answer.

Comment: sure, blame the switch statement... you should rather check/verify (echo!) that it executes the code you *think* it should execute

Comment: I did change `exit` to `break`. The problem still exists

Comment: @KarolyHorvath the echo didn't give any result. The result is empty for $_SESSION['next']. This lead me to believe that the session won't work under switch statement?

Comment: Also `<>` is not an unequal operator in PHP that I'm aware of. Use `!=` instead!

Comment: Update: `<>` is valid, but is almost never used.

Answer (score 3):

Your switch is all wrong. [Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) and try this:

```
<?php

switch ((isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '')){
    case 'abc':
        $_SESSION['next'] = 'AAA';
        echo "<script>top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/'</script>";
        break;
    case 'def':
        $_SESSION['next'] = 'BBB';
        echo "<script>top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/'</script>";
        break;
    case 'ghi':
        $_SESSION['next'] = 'CCC';
        echo "<script>top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/'</script>";
        break;
    default:
        echo "<script>top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/'</script>";
        break;
}
```

You're using `exit` in your `switch`, which (unless you want your script to end at the switch) is a no-no. Instead, you have to use the `break` keyword.

You also use semicolons and curly braces for each case.

```
case 'ghi';{ ... }
```

***NO!*** Proper usage is

```
case 'ghi':
    .
    .
    .
    break;
```

**Update:** I just noticed you use this line:

```
if ($user_id <> '0' && $user_id <> '') { ... }
```

What is `<>` doing in PHP code? The "standard" operator for "not equals" is `!=` in PHP. Use it correctly or no one will want to use your code.

**Second update:** You never set `$_SESSION['next']` in your `default` case. It's very likely that your `switch` is always going to the `default` case. This would cause the behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: I did change exit to break. The problem still exists

Comment: @Nick Did you remove the semicolons and curly braces from your `case`s?

Comment: No offense but I think the problem is beyond `semicolon`, `break`, and `<>`. I tried your approach but the problem still exists, and I know that the reasonable way is to use `!=` but I do have specific reason to use `<>` instead, which solve my problem with facebook error 'CSRF state token'.

Comment: What's "not working"? Is it always going into the `default`? Echo the value you're passing to the `switch` to find out what's going on there.

Comment: No Matt. What is not working is that I am not able to set $_SESSION['next'] under switch/case condition. The solution provided by Iserni should solve the session issue because the $_SESSION['next'] is set outside the switch/case condition.

Comment: If `$_SESSION['next']` isn't being set, it's likely because you're entering the `default` case - you never set `$_SESSION['next']` in there to begin with. The issue *is* your `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
if (($user_id != '0') && ($user_id != ''))
```

(parentheses, and the != operator)

and also a DRYer switch:

```
$page = array_key_exists('page', $_GET) ? $_GET['page'] : '';

switch ($page) {
    case 'abc':
        $next = 'AAA';
        $loc  = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/';
        break;
    case 'def':
        $next = 'BBB';
        $loc  = 'https://www.example.com/yyy/';
        break;
    ... // and so on
}
if (isset($next)) {
    $_SESSION['next'] = $next;
    // If it does not work, you have problems with your session ID, maybe?
}

// I find this syntax easier
print <<<SCRIPT

<script type="text/javascript">
    top.location.href = '$loc';
</script>

SCRIPT;
exit();
```

Comment: Parentheses aren't necessary in the `if` statement there. They won't hurt, but it's sort of voodoo programming.

Comment: Well, I tend to over-use parentheses. That way, I don't need to worry about precedences. At times, I even indent them -- I find the code clearer. Of course it is also a matter of habit. That said, yours was undoubtedly a useful comment: my voodoo is not your voodoo, I tend to forget.